# Can't access inputs wrapped by component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a modal as component and inside the component some inputs. The action which needs access to these inputs is defined in my component but can't access them at all..

Any Ideas ?

admin-modal.hbs:

```
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{title}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              {{yield}}
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{btnCancel}}</button>
              <button {{action "submit" inputTitle}} type="button" class="btn btn-primary">{{btnSave}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

index.hbs:

```
    {{#admin-modal id="modNewCat" title="Kategorie hinzufügen" submit="newCat"}}
      <form>
        <div class="form-group">
          {{input type="text" class="form-control" id="form.inputTitle" value=inputTitle placeholder="Kategorie Name"}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="inputDesc" name="inputDesc" placeholder="Kategorie Beschreibung"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group cp">
              {{input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="inputColor" value="form.inputColor" placeholder="Kategorie Farbe" }}
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    {{/admin-modal}}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as seen in the link I posted, there's no way for those two contexts to interact directly. You'll have to send an action up from the input then pass data down to the component. It seems very roundabout, but it is good practice (and design).

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you just need to bind the value, because component is isolated:

```
{{#admin-modal inputTitle=inputTitle id="modNewCat" title="Kategorie hinzufügen" submit="newCat"}}
```

Comment: but still can't access it from the surrounded form in my component..

Comment: but the action: {{action "submit" inputTitle}} is working now, right? i have tested this on Ember 1.11 and its successfully passing this property...

Comment: yes but as soon as I used the public name it works..